# Does constructible and analytically open imply Zariski open

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $U$ be a constructible subset of a complex algebraic variety. Is the following statement true?

If $U$ is open in the analytic topology, then $U$ is open in the Zariski topology on $X$.

Comment: Cor. 2.3, Exp. XII, SGA1.